# How can I set the contenteditable true on clicking the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have an array. In which I have strored the list of tags. Now what I want, that on click on the element like ( h1, a, strong )  it will find the tags in the given array and apply contenteditable true on the element. On clicking outside the tag or other element the contenteditable will again set to false.

Currently I am using this code for changing the contenteditable true but if I want to edit p I have to write a new code for p same as strong h2, h3, h4 etc

```
$('h1').click(function(event) {
    $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'true');
});
```

```js
$(function(){
  
  $(".textTemplate").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    zIndex: 2500
  });
  
  $( ".editorDesignView" ).droppable({
    accept: '.textTemplate',
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var html = `<div id="" class="dynamic"><h1 contenteditable="false">Title</h1><p contenteditable="false" style="padding: 5px;">Add your text here.</p></div>`;
  $(html).appendTo(this).hide().slideDown();     
      }
  });
    
  $(document).on('click', 'h1', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'true');
 });
});
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
#wrapper {width: 100%; height: 100vh;}
.templateWrapper {width: 30%; height: 100%;float:left;overflow-y: scroll;}
.editorBlock {width: 70%; height: 100%;float:left;position: relative;background-color:#f1f1f1}


.editorDesignView {width: 100%; height: 100%;}

.dynamic {
   background: #4073ff;width: 80%; margin: 10px auto; padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="templateWrapper">
    <div class="textTemplate" style="margin-top:20px;" class="template">
        <div>drag me</div>
    </div>
   
    
  </div>
  <div class="editorBlock" style="height:100%;">
    <div class="editorDesignView" style="height:100%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works for me

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Ok. But please help me

Comment: How can i help you when I can't reproduce your problem

Comment: If you want to attach event to multiple elements then you can do that with `$('h1,h2,h3,h4,p,strong')` or `$('*')` for all elements!

Comment: @PrashantShirke But what if I do not want it to apply on div, section

Comment: as @CarstenLøvboAndersen saied; code works.

Comment: @user7791702 just add the required selectors comma separated or use `$('*')` for all

Comment: you mean to say if you are having div within ('h1,h2,h3,h4,p,strong'), then those should not be content editable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with following code.

Attach event to all elements except html,body and div to make contenteditable and for other elements attach event to make non content editable.

As per your requirement you can add selectors in `$array` comma seperated.

```
var $array=[ 'body', 'div', 'html' ];
var notSelectorString = $array.join(",");
$('*').not(notSelectorString).on('click', function(event) {
   $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'true');
}).on("focusout",function(e){  $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'false');});

$(notSelectorString).on('click', function(event) {
   $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'false');
});
```

Comment: If I want to add array in not tag which contain $array=[ 'body', 'div', 'html' ] how can I do that

Comment: One last thing, on clicking outside the tag or other element the contenteditable will again set to false. means ( suppose h1 is editable but when I click to p or out side h1 area the contenteditable will set to false in h1.)

Comment: then you can set contenteditable false on focusout event. Check updated answer!

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

**Solved your issue please use this code it will help you better**

```
$(document).on('click', '*', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'true');
    });
```

Comment: This does not address what happens when there is already an editable element and another element gets clicked.

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle, you are missing a bit of jquery for the p element.

```js
$(function(){
  
  $(".textTemplate").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    zIndex: 2500
  });
  $( ".editorDesignView" ).droppable({
    accept: '.textTemplate',
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var html = '<div id="" style="background: #4073ff;width: 80%; margin: 10px auto; padding: 10px;"><h1 contenteditable="false">Title</h1><p contenteditable="false" style="padding: 5px;">Add your text here.</p></div>';
  $(html).appendTo(this).hide().slideDown();
  
      }
    });
    
  $(document).on('click', 'h1', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'true');
 });
    $(document).on('click', 'p', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'true');
 });


});
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
#wrapper {width: 100%; height: 100vh;}
.templateWrapper {width: 30%; height: 100%;float:left;overflow-y: scroll;}
.editorBlock {width: 70%; height: 100%;float:left;position: relative;background-color:#f1f1f1}


.editorDesignView {width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="templateWrapper">
    <div class="textTemplate" style="margin-top:20px;" class="template">
        <div>drag me</div>
    </div>
   
    
  </div>
  <div class="editorBlock" style="height:100%;">
    <div class="editorDesignView" style="height:100%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know that but tell me if I want to apply contenteditable true on h2, h3, h4 etc so I have to write this code many times

Answer (score -1):

You can use a rather dangerous js function named `eval()`, which can execute code from a string, this way you can put it in a `for` loop and change the integer after the `h` every time.

Comment: `eval()` is in no way a proper solution for this.